# Play : Invalid method Code length

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

I have added one condition on my HTML page that is

```
#{if userObject == null}
<a href="/login">Text</a>
#{/if}
```

The code is working fine on the dev mode and getting this error in PROD mode.

```
SEVERE: Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 65561 in class file Template_M1175588447$_run_closure1_closure2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$TClassLoader.defineTemplate(GroovyTemplate.java:77)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.compile(GroovyTemplate.java:133)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:184)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:194)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.scan(TemplateLoader.java:194)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.getAllTemplate(TemplateLoader.java:164)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:501)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:273)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:131)
```

Is there any way out on this

Comment: Without seeing what "something" and "somepath" are and the code of the methods that create them we can't really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is not related to the code you added, but to having a template "too big" that goes over the allowed lines size (in Java) for a method.

Probably you are xtending big templates or your page is really long.

Comment: I am not sure for the problem, But I did what you said and it works. I deleted some lines, added code in external file's and imported that file. This work's. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same, don't suppose you can share details of how you refactored your code?

Answer (score 1):

As said on the official Java documentation, that means the jvm tries to read a class file that is malformed. Thus, try to delete all class files, tmp folder and recompile.